# I'm trying to graphic with django using python but jump IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, django

Looks like simple but I'm starting code and I don't know what to do or why this error happened.

What I'm trying is to make an example graphic in django that's all not with success, all the information showed is confusing me.

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def home(request):
    
    plt.plot(range(10))
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html')


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'app1/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

and jump the next error

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/LabBD/Web_DB/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/LabBD/app1/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/corbin/ProyectoDB/LabBD/app1/views.py", line 11
    
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I will apreciate all your help.

Comment: It isn't clear which line in your code snippet is line 11, but I am assuming that it is the blank line after `def home(request):`
Have you tried to remove that blank line - or add a comment (start the line with a #).

Comment: I'm going to try

Comment: Line 11 it's of "return render(request, 'app1/about.html', {'title': 'About'})" but before it worked and the changes that I made were not there, but "def home(request):"

Comment: Worked without graphics

Comment: %c3%a9ndez-macea - it isn't clear exactly what you did to fix the problem but the issue wasn't the plotting (or the attempt at i) . The error was about an unexpected indent. Doing that plot wouldn't have done what you thought it might - but it wouldn't have caused the error you got as far as I can tell.